# Graph Editor - Moving only one side of a tangent for multiple keyframes

Tags: animation, graph-editor

This is a question from a Maya user.
I can't find this in the manuals, and I feel really dumb. They all take it for granted.

I have a lot of animated properties in the graph editor. They all do the same. I'm moving them around together. But I want to change them to Free Tangents, which I did, and change their animation by moving the handles on both sides of the point.

But I can't do it. I changed to Maya preset in the settings, so I could do it the same way I do it there. But there is NO WAY to move the tangents by selecting and moving them using the handles...

**EDIT:**
Moving one tangent is possible by using Middle Mouse Button, BUT this doesn't work at all for several tangents. I want to move all of them at the same time.

How do you do it?

Comment: Nope. I said i changed it to Free tangents. So I already did that.

In fact I'm going to update the info, because i found out something else.

Comment: Do you want to select only one part of several FCurve handles and move them together ? Then I think you should select all the points with `A`, then use `C` to turn on `Circle Select` and deselect parts of handles you don't want to move (assuming `V` -> `Free` was selected before).

Comment: @poor you edited my question, but changed drastically the meaning of the title. I mean, moving a tangent independently, not independent handles. Moving one handle, independently.

Comment: Oops, sorry darkgaze :) Only wanted to clear up things, roll it back. sorry!

Comment: @poor Nah, i made it even better :D

Answer (score 3):

To scale only one side of a group with free tangents:

- Select the set of keys
- Press <kbd>C</kbd> and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> to deselect the tangents you do not want to scale
- Right click to confirm the operation
- Press <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> to scale along the horizontal axis as required

[image: Here is a demo]

Comment: This is not the answer to my question. Scaling doesn't work for one side of the tangents but both.

Comment: @SamirRahamtalla You can use http://gfycat.com/ to encode your screen capture to a .gif, which is supported here. For the key markup see this meta: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/524/what-case-should-letters-inside-kbd-tags-be.